# Android SDK: What's the license of the included icons?

Tags: android, mobile, icons

I have to write a paper about app of mine, but in my UI I've used icons which came included with Android-Studio. The problem is I need the license for these icons and I just can't find it.
Does anyone know how these icons are licensed or where I can look this up? (please don't just say developer.android.com, I've looked there and I can't find it (q_q) )
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The license is Apache 2.0, as stated on the Icons webpage in Material.io here: https://material.io/tools/icons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

As given in the screenshot, it clearly says the license is **[Apache License version 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt)**

Comment: Haha, happy to help.